# Ruby Date 1 month ago to String

Tags: ruby, date

I need to calculate the date 1 month from today in Ruby and convert it to a `String` in the format:

> yyyy-dd-mmThh:MM:ss (e.g. 2014-08-26T00:00:00)

I have tried: `(DateTime.now - Date.today.prev_month).to_datetime.strftime("%FT%T")` but I get a method does not exist exception.

Comment: Do you use `activesupport` (it's the part of `rails`)?

Comment: your exeption `undefined method 'to_datetime' for`?

Comment: sorry, you want one month ago or one month in the future?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
require 'date'

d = Date.today.prev_month # or Date.today.next_month, depending what you want
 => #<Date: 2014-12-27 ((2457019j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
d.strftime("%FT%T")
 => "2014-12-27T00:00:00"
```

Comment: i was confused actually - the title says previous month, but the first sentence is `I need to calculate the date 1 month from today`

Comment: 1 month ago is also '1 month from today', but in another direction. :) Anyway, this answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
2.0.0-p247 :004 > require 'date'
 => false 
2.0.0-p247 :005 > Date.today.prev_month
 => #<Date: 2014-10-27 ((2456958j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
2.0.0-p247 :006 > Date.today.prev_month.to_s
 => "2014-10-27" 
2.0.0-p247 :008 > Date.today.prev_month.strftime("%F%T")
 => "2014-10-2700:00:00" 
2.0.0-p247 :009 >
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(DateTime.now - 1.month).strftime("%FT%T").to_s
```

PS: I am sure this works fine with rails. Please confirm if it works independently on ruby too?

**UPDATE**:

As pointed out on comment below, this will work only if you have `activesupport` lib

Comment: only with `activesupport` lib.

Comment: ohh I though so, thanks will update my answer to reflect this

Comment: Without Rails you'd use `DateTime.now.prev_month(1).strftime("%FT%T")`, and with Rails `1.month.ago.strftime("%FT%T")`

Comment: @Stefan i think it should be `DateTime.now.prev_month.strftime("%FT%T")` , `DateTime.now.prev_month(1).strftime("%FT%T")` gives `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`

Comment: I cant seem to get this to work, ruby doesnt seem to think activesupport seems to exist

Comment: @clairharrison does stefan's answer work? `DateTime.now.prev_month.strftime("%FT%T")`

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE 2021

You can write this, for simplicity:

```rb
1.month.ago.beginning_of_month.to_s

# Or

1.month.ago.end_of_month.to_s
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to ActiveSupport, or even Date, nor DateTime, then you can use something like this for 30 days ago:

```rb
(Time.now - 60*60*24*30).strftime("%FT%T")
```